# Python 3 execution order quirk with print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this work? I would think `sup` is passed to `print` as is, and printed. Then print returns some value and `capitalize()` is run on that. What is going on here?

```
print('sup').capitalize()
```

**Edit: I'm new to Python, I've only downloaded Python 3, and I didn't realize `python` was using an old version that was already installed... thanks! (I can see why they changed this)**

Comment: You are running this with Python 2. On python 3 this prints "sup" and then fails to look up `capitalize` on `None`.

Comment: @PavelAnossov That's going to be the only answer me thinks. If the OP were using Python 3.x, this would be an `AttributeError`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by local conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Python 2, and it's being interpreted as this:

```
print ('sup').capitalize()
```

`print` is not a function in Python 2; it's a keyword.